# What happens when you wear a hydrophobic suit and dive into water?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials

Do you float above the surface or you drown ?

Comment: Would Archimedes principle be relevant?

Comment: You can't swim?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your buyuoncy, you sink. Surface tension of water is not strong enough to hold something with the weight and shape of a human being afloat. This works for [water striders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerridae#Nature_of_the_ability_to_walk_on_water) and maybe some tiny geckos. What will happen is that air bubbles cling to your suit longer than otherwise, maybe even forming a thin air layer until turbulence shears them away.

[Hydrophobic behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrophobe) does not - strictly speaking - mean that something repels water, it means that there's no attraction between the hydrophobic surface and individual water molecules so that the adhesion between water molecules is far stronger.

Comment: So I'll drown faster?

Comment: no, *maybe* the extra buyouancy from 'clingy' ari bubbles is even measurable but my guess is there won't be a huge difference

Comment: @user17616  You would drown dry.

Comment: @user17616 only if you dont know how to swim. Or if your legs dont reach the bottom while your head is still on the surface ;)